# SQL 400 Grouping by expressions of type STRUCT is not allowed

Tags: sql

I am running the following query:

```
%%bigquery --project $project_id q6b
# YOUR QUERIES HERE
SELECT license, ROUND(AVG(watch_count)) avg_watch_count
FROM `cs145-fa21-326819.project2.github_repos` repos
JOIN `cs145-fa21-326819.project2.github_repo_licenses` license
ON repos.lrepo_name = license.lrepo_name
GROUP BY license
ORDER BY avg_watch_count DESC
LIMIT 20
```

And get this error:

```
ERROR:
 400 Grouping by expressions of type STRUCT is not allowed at [6:10]

(job ID: d5148f44-0cfb-49f2-bfc4-a1532b5f7b49)

                  -----Query Job SQL Follows-----                  

    |    .    |    .    |    .    |    .    |    .    |    .    |
   1:# YOUR QUERIES HERE
   2:SELECT license, ROUND(AVG(watch_count)) avg_watch_count
   3:FROM `cs145-fa21-326819.project2.github_repos` repos
   4:JOIN `cs145-fa21-326819.project2.github_repo_licenses` license
   5:ON repos.lrepo_name = license.lrepo_name
   6:GROUP BY license
   7:ORDER BY avg_watch_count DESC
   8:LIMIT 20
    |    .    |    .    |    .    |    .    |    .    |    .    |
```

Is there a problem here?
I am trying to join a list of repos with their licenses and plot the watch count against the license.

Comment: What is it about the error message that you don’t  understand? It seems pretty clear and unambiguous to me

Comment: You get an award for the most unhelpful answer of the year